# What am I unable to send email using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-email

**I have turned on the 'allow less secure apps' on my google account.**
But when I submit the password reset form, it goes to the password_reset_done.html and DOESN'T show any error. But the mail is not sending. It's neither in my sentbox nor in the inbox of the email it's supposed to send to.

This is what my **urls.py** looks like :

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('password_reset/',       
                        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="my_app/password_reset.html"), 
                        name="password_reset"),
    path('password_reset/done/',  
                        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="my_app/password_reset_done.html"), 
                        name="password_reset_done"),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
                        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="my_app/password_reset_confirm.html"), 
                        name="password_reset_confirm" ),
    path('reset_password/', 
                        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="my_app/password_reset_complete.html"), 
                        name="password_reset_complete" ),
```

And here is the **settings.py** file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_g_mail_id_here@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**********'
```

I have literally read every other question and tried everything. Nothing is working for me.
I am dying here to find out a solution, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Gmail for this. It's not designed for programmatic email sending.

Instead, use something like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) or [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/). Both have inexpensive or free starter plans.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was not registering user's email ID's through the Djangos default registration form.
Tweaked it a little to add the email field in the form and then the users started recieving the email.
Nothing wrong in the conf file.